# Why cant react native find my navigation route when logging user in?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Im using react native and trying to handle authentication in my app.  I'm having a problem where when the user successfully logs in, my app is unable to navigate them to the home screen.  I am conditionally rendering two different types of navigators based on a value being present in `AsyncStorage`.

The problem seems like it's coming from the `useEffect` hook in `app.js`. When the app loads and the user is not logged in, the `useEffect` hook runs once. Then when I successfully login and try to navigate the user to the home screen, the app doesnt know about the `<Drawer.Navigator>` that I render in my else condition and because of that is not able to navigate there.

What am I doing wrong?

App.js

```
export default function App() {
  const [token, setToken] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("use effect");
    readData();
  });
  const readData = async () => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
      if (value !== null) {
        setToken(value);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
        <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
          {token == null ? (
            <Stack.Navigator
              initialRouteName="Login"
              screenOptions={{
                headerShown: false,
              }}
            >
              <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
              <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
              <Stack.Screen name="Verify" component={VerifyScreen} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
          ) : (
            <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
              <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
              <Drawer.Screen name="Episodes" component={EpisodeListScreen} />
              <Drawer.Screen name="Account" component={AccountScreen} />
            </Drawer.Navigator>
          )}
        </NavigationContainer>
      </PaperProvider>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}
```

AuthContext.js

```
import createDataContext from "./createDataContext";
import authApi from "../api/auth";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";
import * as RootNavigation from "../common/RootNavigation";

const authReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "add_error":
      return { ...state, errorMessage: action.payload };
    case "login":
      return { errorMessage: "", token: action.payload };
    case "logout":
      return { token: null, errorMessage: "" };
    case "clear_error_message":
      return { ...state, errorMessage: "" };
    default:
      state;
  }
};

const register = (dispatch) => ({ fullName, email, password }) => {
  const id = uuid();
  const user = { id, fullName, email, password };
  authApi
    .put("register", user)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        RootNavigation.navigate("Verify");
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      dispatch({
        type: "add_error",
        payload: "Something went wrong during registation.",
      });
    });
};

const login = (dispatch) => async ({ email, password }) => {
  // make api request to api
  try {
    const user = { email, password };
    const response = await authApi.post("/login", user);
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("token", response.data.access_token);
    dispatch({ type: "login", payload: response.data.access_token });
    RootNavigation.navigate("Episodes");
  } catch (e) {
    dispatch({ type: "add_error", payload: e.response.data.message });
  }
};

const tryLocalLogin = (dispatch) => async () => {
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
  if (token) {
    dispatch({ type: "login", payload: token });
    RootNavigation.navigate("Episodes");
  } else {
    RootNavigation.navigate("Login");
  }
};

const logout = (dispatch) => async () => {
  await AsyncStorage.removeItem("token");
  dispatch({ type: "logout" });
  RootNavigation.navigate("Login");
  try {
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
};

const clearErrorMessage = (dispatch) => () => {
  dispatch({ type: "clear_error_message" });
};

export const { Provider, Context } = createDataContext(
  authReducer,
  { register, login, logout, tryLocalLogin, clearErrorMessage },
  { token: null, errorMessage: "" }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just taking a quick look at this, are you saying your issue is the Drawer.Navigator never seems to load in / work?

If so I think your issue is that every time the component loads it will assess the token as null, as it will be waiting on the Async function and you are assessing token as null on each load as its rendering before the Async returns anything.

One fix may be to use `useState` and set the token (or at least a boolean to indicate its present) in state. This may help, because setting state will cause a re-render and in turn assess the latest state value (which will for example be tokenState !== null) and in turn may render your drawer navigator.

If this doesn't help, could you also not generally look to use state across your app to handle if the user is signed in and get their token etc? Sure, it may occasionally mean firing an API call on app load sometimes, but I remember a while ago generally looking into Redux (there may be better cross-application app state management tools now) to replace a lot of what I was using Async Storage for.

Comment: So its not just the Drawer.Navigator that isnt showing. It can be either that OR the Stack.Navigator that doesnt show. It just depends if the token is present or not in AsyncStorage when I load the application. If token is in AyncStorage and I load the app, I will be shown the Drawer.Navigator, but if I try and logout, which directs the user to the login page (a child of Stack.Navigator), I am facing the same issue.  Once the app renders one navigator, it seems it is unable to ever render the other.

Comment: Hmm ok, I'd still be interested to see if useState improves this. If you can call the function and after it's run, fire a .then() or similar that sets the login state. I'd then query on state in place of where you currently check if token == null.